# how to load multiple json objects in python

Tags: python, json

I have 10,000's of json objects in a <s>json</s> file in following format :

```
{ "a": 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : {
          "d":3
        }
}{ "e" : 4,
  "f" : 5,
  "g" : {
         "h":6
        }
}
```

**How can I load these as a json object?**

Two methods that I've tried with corresponding error :

Method 1 :

```
>>> with open('test1.json') as jsonfile:
...     for line in jsonfile:
...             data = json.loads(line)
...
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 10)
```

Method 2 :

```
>>> with open('test1.json') as jsonfile:
...     data = json.load(jsonfile)      
...
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 7 column 1 (char 46)
>>>
```

I've read the related questions but none of them helped.

Comment: The first bit of code you've posted contains two JSON objects, not one. That's probably the cause of the `json.load` error.

Comment: Are there always blank lines between the objects, and are thoae the only blank lines?

Comment: @DanielRoseman no. I've edited. Have a look now.

Comment: "in a json file" it is not a json file, because that isn't a valid JSON-formatted string, which is why the parser is failing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry. actual file was very big. Hence I tried to create `mvce`. Can you say why it's not JSON file. May be I should change `I have 10,000's of json objects in a json file in following format ` to `I have 10,000's of json objects in a file in following format `?

Comment: Is there a possibility to change the process that generate JSON file to insert 2, or more, break lines between each JSON? So the approach that has @DanielRoseman thought, would to work.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I created 'a.json' file. then using `json.dump(json,json_file)` for 10,000 iteration. So in one iteration json is valid but it keeps other json one after other hence breaking json file format. Is there any solution ?

Comment: if you can change how to generate the file I'd suggest to change it in a way to add a `[` at beginning, a `,` between each objects and a `]` at the end

Comment: @krishna serialize it as a list of objects, or use a different format, like json-lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of file you described is not a valid JSON object this is why bot approaches are not working.

To transform in something you can load with `json.load(fd)` you have to:

1. add a `[` at the beginning of the file
2. add a `,` between each object
3. add a `]` at the very end of the file

then you can use the Method 2.
For instance:

```
[ { "a": 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : {
      "d":3
    }
  }, { "e" : 4,
       "f" : 5,
       "g" : {
         "h":6
       }
  }
]
```

is a valid JSON array

If the file format is exactly as you've described you could do

```
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    new_data = data.replace('}{', '},{')
    json_data = json.loads(f'[{new_data}]')
```

Comment: Your second method helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the best approach if you don't want to change the source file would be to use json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode()
It would allow you to iterate through each valid json object you have in the file

```
from json import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError

decoder = JSONDecoder()
content = '{ "a": 1,  "b": 2,  "c": { "d":3 }}{ "e": 4, "f": 5,  "g": {"h":6 } }'

pos = 0
while True:
    try:
        o, pos = decoder.raw_decode(content, pos)
        print(o)
    except JSONDecodeError:
        break
```

Would print your two Json objects

Comment: Need to increment pos, see code sample from @noredistribution below

Comment: It seems the second positional argument to `raw_decode` vanished. :(

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel said in comment, focuses on the pattern of start/end of JSONs chunks.As you updated, the pattern is `}{`.

Load all data to an string, replace this pattern to a pattern you can handle, and split it into a list of strings of valid JSON data. At the end, iterate over list.

```
{ "a": 1,
"b" : 2,
"c" : {
        "d":3
        }
}{ "e" : 4,
"f" : 5,
"g" : {
        "h":6
        }
}
```

Load data to a list of json valid strings

```
with open('/home/mauro/workspace/test.json') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
```

Replace the pattern

```
data = data.replace('}{', '}\n\n{')
```

Then, split it into a list of json strings valids

```
data = data.split('\n\n')
```

In the end, iterate over list of json strings

```
for i in data:
    print json.loads(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Thiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4788285/thiago-c-cunha)'s answer worked for me but only if pos is being increased by one, otherwise it'll always just print one object

so like this:

```
from json import JSONDecoder, JSONDecodeError

def json_decoder(data):
    decoder = JSONDecoder()
    pos = 0
    result = []
    while True:
        try:
            o, pos = decoder.raw_decode(data, pos)
            result.append(o)
            pos +=1
        except JSONDecodeError:
            break
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this script that takes advantage of the exception including the character where the json ends:

```
import json
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

with open("file.json", 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
start=0
end=len(contents)
json_objects=[]
while start < len(contents):
    try:
        json_objects.append(json.loads(contents[start:end]))
        print(f"Loaded from {start} to {end}")
        start=end
        end=len(contents)
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        end=start+e.pos
for json_object in json_objects:
    print(len(json.dumps(json_object)))
```

It is not at all efficient and requires the entire file to be loaded into memory, but it does work

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    { 
      "a": 1,
      "b" : 2,
      "c" : {
              "d":3
            }
    },
    { 
      "e" : 4,
      "f" : 5,
      "g" : {
             "h":6
            }
    }
]
```

First your json file should look
like this, second load your file like json.loads(file.read())